# Include a module as a dependency into a KMM project's shared module

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a working KMM application, and I have a java module, `mymodule`, that I created with `File->New->Module->Java or Kotlin library`.

The module exists at the top level beside `androidApp`, `iosApp` and `shared`. In my `settings.gradle.kts` I have `include(":mymodule")`.

I want to use `mymodule` in the `shared` module. So I go into the `shared` module's `build.gradle.kts` and I try to include my module in `commonMain`:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    ...    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
          dependencies {
              implementation(project(":mymodule"))
          }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

And the error is `Could not resolve MyKMMApplication:mymodule:unspecified` and:

```
Could not resolve project :mymodule.
Required by:
    project :shared
```

Things I've tried

- I can put `dependencies { implementation(project(":mymodule")) }` at the bottom of `shared`'s `build.gradle.kts` and but still the same error appears
- As to test if there's other problems, I can also import `mymodule` into the Android project without problems
- I can include `implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.5.3")` in `commonMain` and see those classes in the `shared` module no problem
- The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-add-dependencies.html#dependency-on-another-multiplatform-project) say you can include another multiplatform module, but nothing about a normal module.

How can I include a modules into KMM's shared module as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the module you include into `shared` needs to be a multiplatform module. It's `build.gradle.kts` file should look something like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
  jvm()
  iosX64()
  iosArm32()
  iosArm64()
}
```

And it's project structure should look something like: `mymodule/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/example/mymodule/`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm working on an Android app with some shared modules - a adding more targets (in my case the ios ones) solved the issue!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I created a module where my source path was `src/main/kotlin/com/example` and just by renaming my path to `src/commonMain/kotlin/com/example`, where commonMain is the same as my multiplatform common main source, it worked!